# Masking an Image by Manipulating Pixels through Conditions

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, color-space

I have read an image in python using **RGBA color space**. The size of an image is **640 by 960** and is stored to an array called **img_array** . Now each element in the array contains [R,G,B,A], say for example [21,34,53,255]. I want to filter my image pixels by turning pixels into black [0,0,0,255] which does not satisfy the conditional below.

```
R > 95 and G > 40 and B > 20 and R > G and R > B and | R - G | > 15 and A > 15
```

How will I do it in python? All I know is to set pixels to black which is not within the lower and upper boundaries using cv2.inrange(). Below is my sample code:

```
 #import the necessary packages
 import imutils
 import numpy as np
 import argparse
 import cv2

 # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
 ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 ap.add_argument("-i", "--image",help = "path to the image file")
 args = vars(ap.parse_args())

 #read image with alpha channel
 img_array = cv2.imread(args["image"], -1)

 rgba_lower_bound = np.array([0, 59, 59,2], dtype = "uint8")
 rgba_upper_bound = np.array([20, 255, 255,255], dtype = "uint8")    
 skinMask = cv2.inRange(img_array, rgb_lower_bound, rgb_upper_bound)
 skin = cv2.bitwise_and(img_array, img_array, mask = skinMask)
 cv2.imshow("images", skin)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Am i correct in saying you want to write an if statement for the conditional above?

Comment: @GPPK Yeah, I want to make all the pixels in my image not satisfying the condition above to black. How will I do that?

Comment: Note here that you say you want to turn the pixels to *black* but then say `[0,0,0,0]`. Anything with a 0 in the alpha channel is *transparent* and not black. If you want black, then it should be `[0,0,0,255]`; if you want transparent, then it doesn't matter what the other values are, so long as the fourth value is 0.

Comment: Ok, I'll update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `R, G, B, A` are all numpy arrays with the same shape, created by something like:

```
R, G, B, A = cv2.split(img_array)
```

simply create a mask using the same conditionals; since they're `numpy` arrays, use `&` instead of `and`:

```
mask = (R > 95) & (G > 40) & (B > 20) & (R > G) & (R > B) & (abs(R - G) > 15) & (A > 15)
```

Then to set everything *not* satisfying the condition to black:

```
img_array[~mask] = [0, 0, 0, 255]
```

Note here the `mask` will be two-channel, and will be broadcasted to all the channels in `img_array`. Also note `~` inverts a numpy boolean array, so this is indexing by wherever `mask` is `False`, which is what you want.

---

Some more info on transparency: if the alpha channel is 0, that means fully transparent, and if it's 255 (for a unsigned 8-bit image), that means opaque. If you want the image to be *transparent* at those locations instead of black, you can just invert the mask, turn it into a `uint8` array, and then merge it back into one image, like so:

```
R, G, B, A = cv2.split(img_array)
mask = (R > 95) & (G > 40) & (B > 20) & (R > G) & (R > B) & (abs(R - G) > 15) & (A > 15)
new_A = 255*(~mask).astype(np.uint8)
new_img_array = cv2.merge([R, G, B, new_A])
```

This way you're not losing any of the color information in R, G, B should you want to keep it.

Comment: As a C++ developer python never ceases to amaze me. This is genius.

Comment: Ok I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def set_to_black(T, image):
    # grab the image dimensions
    h = image.shape[0]
    w = image.shape[1]

    # loop over the image, pixel by pixel
    for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            if (conditional) # I couldn't be bothered to write it all out
            # Set the pixel to black
            image[y, x] = [0, 0, 0, 255]

    # return the thresholded image
    return image
```

Comment: So in general you want to avoid looping through the pixels in a numpy array as it's usually slow in Python---numpy operations will loop through in C in the backend---but with this many conditionals, my method loops through the array for each conditional (in this case, 7 times) which could be slower depending on image size. I'd test both approaches.

Comment: Ok I'll try, which is better.

Comment: Depends what you mean by better, They should both give the same results. I have no idea if one is quicker than the other, and @AlexanderReynolds solution is certainly smaller